# Power BI - Filtering a Table based on selection in a Bar Graph

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

[image: I'm trying to filter my table when i select a value in the graph (also would expect to see the count match the selection]I'm pretty new to Power BI.
I have a number of measures I've created in my Power BI app, data related to information requests that come to my team.
I've put these measures into a Bar Chart. I also have a table that lists details about these data requests. I want to be able to select an item in the Bar Graph and have the records in the Table to adjust to just those related to the selection.

I did this once by accident when i was fiddling around, now I can't figure out how i did it.
I also have a date filter set to affect all of my pages.

Any advice would be awesome.
Thanks in advance.
Jason

Comment: If there is a relationship between table and measure when you select one data in bar chart it will automatically filter table data

Comment: as mentioned, if there is direct relation, out of box you should be able to view/filter specific info. if you can add  some more information to your question such as screenshot of your report, it will be easy to visualize

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My data is just one table taken from our system tracking research requests. I made some measures based on criteria from the table. I am trying to put these measure on a graph and then have the table filter to the selection when i click on a value in the graph.  This is an example of one of my measures if it helps. All are similar :

Comment: Requests with Use of PHI for Research - Denied = 
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Vizor_Data'),
        'Vizor_Data'[ProblemArea]= "Other BORN & Agent Work",
        'Vizor_Data'[IsResearch]="Yes",
        Vizor_Data[SubstateID]="Incomplete - Cancelled"
)+0

Answer (score 0):

Try going to **Model** (highlighted in the screenshot, left side) and then **Manage Relationships** (highlighted as well). Then click on Autodetect. If Autodetect does not solve your problem, then you will have to create new relationships manually. 
[image]

Comment: Ok I'll try that. I think part of my issue. My model is really basic. Just imported a data dump from the DB with the data, so my model is just a single Table. Perhaps I need to two instances so that when i click on one of my measures that I have created it will filter the similar table?...not sure if that makes sense.  I used to do this kinda thing in Qlik and I'm just trying to wrap my head around how Power BI does it too.  Thanks again all.

Comment: I still am not able to get this to work.  Its odd though I feel like it should be pretty straight forward. I feel like I missed a setting somewhere.  My data model is just one table that i pulled in from an excel file. It oulines all the research requests we receive in a period.  I have created a number of measures based on the requests:  ie: requests that use personal health information (PHI) for research, requests use of PHI for non-research, requests with disclosure of PHI for research, requests with de-identified data for research , requests with de-identified for non-research...

Comment: continued...What I am trying ot do is put these values on a graph with a table below. When i select a value on the graph i want the table to filter to just those records that fall in the selected value. I hope that helps to clarify

Comment: @JasonR - can you show a screenshot of the fileds you have for both table and chart? It should be really straightforward if you only have one table and you don't need to create a new measure.